# How to Change 'SKU' Label in product detail page using CSV Magento2

Tags: magento2, custom, csv

I don't have experience with change name using CSV. Actually, I want to change Name From 'SKU' to 'Product ID' using CSV in magento2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to change label 'SKU' to 'Product ID' you should change from backend. This is not possible to change using CSV.

Go to Admin => Stores => Attributes => Product => Search Attribute Code **SKU** =>  Attribute Properties Tab => change Default Label SKU to Product ID.

Clear cache from backend once.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for translating SKU to ProductID , please follow this instruction from Magento devdocs

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html

Comment: With using of it i can change add to cart and all things but unable to change "sku"

Comment: I think it happen because SKU it Attribute

Answer (score 0):

we can change product label for product page using below way
app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- change sku label -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" template="CompanyName_ModuleName::product/view/sku_attribute.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/CompanyName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/product/view/sku_attribute.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// phpcs:disable Magento2.Templates.ThisInTemplate.FoundThis

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php
$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_product = $block->getProduct();

if (!$_product instanceof \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product) {
    return;
}

$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
$_className = $block->getCssClass();
$_attributeLabel = $block->getAtLabel();
$_attributeType = $block->getAtType();
$_attributeAddAttribute = $block->getAddAttribute();

$renderLabel = true;
// if defined as 'none' in layout, do not render
if ($_attributeLabel == 'none') {
    $renderLabel = false;
}

if ($_attributeLabel && $_attributeLabel == 'default') {
    $_attributeLabel = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_code)->getStoreLabel();
}
if ($_attributeType && $_attributeType == 'text') {
    $_attributeValue = ($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code))
        ? $_product->getAttributeText($_code)
        : '';
} else {
    $_attributeValue = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->$_call(), $_code);
}
?>

<?php if ($_attributeValue) :?>
<div class="product attribute <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_className) ?>">
    <?php if ($renderLabel) :?>
        <strong class="type"><?php echo __("Product Number:"); ?></strong>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="value" <?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeAddAttribute ?>><?= /* @noEscape */ $_attributeValue ?></div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```